# Xcode6 compiler issue

Tags: ios, xcode

once I run my project, Xcode 6.4 gives an error which is

> Interface Builder Storyboard Compiler Error Line 4140:StartTag:invalid element name

I click on the **xib** or **storyboard** file, and then Xcode crashes.

Comment: Is it your project? Why don't you use Xcode 7?

Comment: Yes,it's my project.Cause it contains swift1.0 file, if use Xcode 7,i need to convert to swift2.0 syntax

Answer (score 2):

If you are using sub-versioning,this happens due to merge conflict and that is why Xcode is throwing that error. 
Once in my project, I too faced the same error and within the xib, i found the following lines :

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
        <image name="55FD63F5-732A-439B-877F-1706F6988CF7" width="24" height="24">
=======
        <image name="0F637DAF-B54F-4BF7-81AC-038AB16B6A9A" width="24" height="24">
>>>>>>> origin/Develop
```

I simply reverted it to previous version. In short,
within the .xib file you will see something like:

```
<<<<<<< someText

// code

=======

// code

>>>>>>> someText
```

Try to resolve the conflict manually, or revert it to last stable version. Hope this helps.

Comment: Really  appreciate! Thank you very much!

Comment: @Joey please consider accepting it if it helped you.